# unique_with laravel:It doesnt work if a particular row is ignored using id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I am using laravel 5.0 and unique_with feature isnt working properly if i want to ignore a particular row using id field.In my database,the id field is named '_id'.Here's my code:

```
$test=Request::segment(2);
```

The `$test` retrieves the id from url properly and the name field is validated using following:

```
'name' => 'Required|Regex:/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.+[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.+[a-zA-Z0-9]/|Max:100|unique_with:permissions,deleted_at,$test=_id',
```

But this isn't working.It allows editing/creating even if name is duplicate whereas it should have done just the opposite!!
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you use [this validator](https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator) because there is no `unique_with` rule out of the box.

Looking at your code, you should use:

```
'name' => 'Required|Regex:/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.+[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.+[a-zA-Z0-9]/|Max:100|unique_with:permissions,deleted_at,' . $test . ' = _id',
```

because when you use single quotes PHP use string literally without putting there any variables values

Comment: Thanks..the single quotes thing was an important point but still i am able to create items with the same name!

Comment: If i remove the '_id' part,then the duplicate item name is solved,but then that particular row isn't ignored!

Comment: i have reworked my code and the duplicate items cant be created i.e. items with same name,by having segregated PUT and POST requests.The only error i am getting now is if i edit an item's name to  another item's name...it shows no error!!